# vuejs : how to unit test main.ts

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-test-utils

I'm using vuejs with typescript, but the question would apply with javascript too.

With vue-test-utils, components are tested using `mount` or `shallowMount`. This way, I've been able to unit test the `App` main component. I'm now wondering how I can unit test the main.ts file, which does already mount the main component:

```js
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  i18n,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

The unit test would check if App component is really mounted into #app.
Unsurprisingly, if I just import `main.ts` in my test, I get this error:

> Cannot find element: #app

Is it possible to do something to create a fake DOM containing an #app element, in which the App component would be mounted?

Comment: What's your test scope? What are you trying to test exactly? Which assertions do you want to make?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use [Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-jquery) to mock a DOM. This way you could setup multiple tests:

- initializing: *Verify that without any parameters it can still instantiate the Vue instance (`undefined` as router, store, etc). Verify that the properties like router etc are added to the prototype
- Mounting: *Create a mock App which renders to your created DOM and verify that the app renders as expected to the correct element*

Especially mounting feels more like functional testing instead of unit testing (as it performs more than a 'unit' of work)

EDIT: *provide example*

```js
// __tests__/main.test.js
'use strict';

test('Can mount app', () => {
  document.body.innerHTML =
    '<div id="app">' +
    '</div>';


  // Executes main file
  require('../src/main');

  const pElement = document.getElementById('example');
  expect(pElement).toBeTruthy();
  expect(pElement.textContent).toEqual('Example');
});
```

With a main file of:

```js
// main.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

And a App.vue file of:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <p id="example">Example</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Rewriting to Typescript is trivial. A few points to notice:

1. The App itself is not mocked (Vue.app as injected in main.js). This can be done by creating a separate mock file or using `jest.fn()` although I have not tested this myself.
2. The tests are not functional testing it but with small changes can be made to verify small units of work

Comment: Can you be more precise on how I can mock a DOM, and how I tell Vue to mount into this DOM?

Comment: Updated post with example